# how to save taxonomy terms in a custom user registration form in D7?

Tags: 7, users, forms

I've got an Implementation of hook_form() on a custom page which I use for user registration.

For example I have this field:

```
function popover_form($form, &$form_state){

    // some other fields are left out here to simplify my question

    $form['second']['education'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Afgeronde opleiding',
      '#options' => popover_get_tax_term_options('education'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('education', NULL),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Then in form_submit() I'm trying to do this:

```
function popover_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $edit = array(

    // some other fields like username, email etc are also left out here.

    // field_firstname is a simple string and works.
    'field_firstname' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['first']['field_firstname']))),
    // education doesn't work ( because it is a taxonomy term ? )
    'education' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['second']['education']))),
  );
  user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
}
```

so either I need to change my submit handler because taxonomy terms are saved differently or I need to update the standard user edit 'view' ( $sitename/user/1/edit ) so the taxonomy terms become visible? Or I'm doing something else wrong?

**EDIT:**
I also found out that it is needed to connect taxonomy terms with the user on the `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` page before you can get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column name for a taxonomy term reference is `'tid'` rather than `'value'`, if you just change that your code should work:

```
$edit = array(
  'field_firstname' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['first']['field_firstname']))),
  'education' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('tid' => $form_state['values']['second']['education']))),
);

user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
```

Comment: I've changed my code but can see the data stored anywhere. where should the data be stored in the database so I can check this is working?

Comment: It'll be in the `field_data_field_education` and `field_revision_field_education` tables

Comment: hmm that table `field_data_field_education` doesn't exists `field_data_education` does exists but is empty

Comment: To be honest I've never seen a user added like the way yo're doing it before, normally you would build up a stdClass for the user with fields attached to it, like `$user = drupal_anonymous_user(); $user->education[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = $tid; user_save($user);`

Comment: thanks that did the trick!, well at least a user is added to `field_data_education` no 'education' value but I can work from here.